# I want to add multi file upload and display in my form

Tags: php, html, mysql, form-submit

I already have one single file upload input field in my form and it well. but I want multiple file input too in it. I tried many ways to add input field of multiple file upload and display code in my form but it seems it is my mistake I am not able to do it.

I have multiple file code but please if anybody can help me to integrate it into my form. my add and edit form is same in one. and please help me on how the uploaded multiple images could be display. I really don't understand like one input one row in table then how can multiple images could display?

below is my code:

1. `edit.php` is my form
2. `multiple.php` and `display.php` files contains code.

**edit.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"><head><!-- Created by Artisteer v4.0.0.58475 -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>library</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">
    <link href='https://sites.google.com/site/99webdemos/favicon.png' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.ie7.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.responsive.css" media="all">


    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.responsive.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
      jQuery(".form-message").fadeOut(10000);
    });
    </script>
   
<style>.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-0 { padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;  }
.ie7 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }
.ie6 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }

</style></head>
<body>
<div id="art-main">
    <div id="art-header-bg" class="clearfix">
            </div>
    <div id="art-hmenu-bg" class="art-bar art-nav clearfix">
    </div>
    <div class="art-sheet clearfix">
<header class="art-header clearfix">


    <div class="art-shapes">
<h1 class="art-headline" data-left="0.5%">
    <a  href="http://www.99demos.blogspot.com" target="_blank">library</a>
</h1>
<h2 class="art-slogan" data-left="87.05%"><a href="http://99demos.blogspot.in/2014/06/createreadupdate-delete-with-image.html"></a></h2>


            </div>

<nav class="art-nav clearfix">
    <div class="art-nav-inner">
    <ul class="art-hmenu"><li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li></ul> 
        </div>
    </nav>

                    
</header>
<div class="art-layout-wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="art-content-layout">
                    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
                        <div class="art-layout-cell art-content clearfix"><article class="art-post art-article">
                                <h2 class="art-postheader">customer form</h2>
                                                
                <div class="art-postcontent art-postcontent-0 clearfix"><div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%" >
        <br>
        
        
<?php
ob_start(); 
include('include/connect.php'); 
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp where id=".$_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query($qry,$conn);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
 {
 
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
         $age = $_POST["age"];
       $gender=$_POST['gender'];
         $martial = $_POST["martial"];
         $contact = $_POST["contact"];
         $email = $_POST["email"];
          $location= $_POST["location"];
               $category= $_POST["category"];
               
        IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
        {
     $file='uploads/'.$row['image'];
     @unlink($file);
                 $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
              $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
     $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
     $image_name=time().".".$ext;
              $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
  }
  else
  {
    $image_name=$row['image'];
  }
  
     $sqlAdd ="update tbl_emp set name='".$name."', age='".$age."', gender='".$gender."', martial='".$martial."', contact='".$contact."', email='".$email."', location='".$location."', category='".$category."', image='".$image_name."'  where id=".$_GET['id'];
     mysql_query($sqlAdd);
         header("Location:add.php?id=".@$_GET['id']."&msg=success");
   exit;
    } } 
}
else
{
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
       $age = $_POST["age"];
       $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        $martial = $_POST["martial"];
        $contact = $_POST["contact"];
         $email = $_POST["email"];
          $location= $_POST["location"];
               $category= $_POST["category"];
              
        IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
   $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
   $image_name=time().".".$ext;

            $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
        }
        $sqlAdd = mysql_query("insert into tbl_emp(name,age,gender,martial,contact,email,location,category,image) VALUES('$name','$age','$gender','$martial','$contact','$email','$location','$category','$image_name')");
        header("Location:index.php?msg=success");
  exit;
    }
}
    ob_end_flush();
 
 if(isset($_GET['msg']))
 {
 ?>
    <div style="color:red;padding-bottom:10px;" class="form-message" align="center"><b>Task completd successfully.</b></div>
    <?php 
 
 }
?>


<form  method="post" name="login" id="login" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table class="table" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Customer Details</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Full Name</td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Firstname Lastname" pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z-'0-9]+" required value="<?php echo @$row['name'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td width="20%">Age</td>
    <td><input name="age" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['2'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Gender</td>
 <td><input type="Radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if ($gender=='male') { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
 Male
 <input type="Radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if ($gender=='female') { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
 Female</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Martial Status</td>
    <td><input name="martial" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['4'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%">Contact Number</td>
    <td><input name="contact" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['5'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">Email Address</td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['6'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Location</td>
    <td><input name="location" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['7'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">category</td>
    <td>
    <select name="category" id="category" value="<?php echo @$row['11'];?>">
    <option <?php if ($category== '1' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="1">1</option>
    <option <?php if ($category== '2' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="2">2</option>
    <option <?php if ($category== '3' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Image</td>
    <td><input name="file" type="file" multiple="" ></td>
    
  </tr>
   <?php
   if(isset($row['image'])) 
   {
   ?>
   <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image'];?> " height="50" width="50"></td>
   </tr>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" class="submit">
    <input name="submit" value="Cancel" type="button" class="submit" onClick="window.location='index.php'">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form> 
<a href="http://dme-medical.com/library/search.php">Go back to list</a>       
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</article></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<footer class="art-footer clearfix">
  <div class="art-footer-inner">
<p>Copyright © 2016. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    <p class="art-page-footer">
      
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>

</div>


</body></html>
```

**multiple.php**

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0){
        //Loop through each file
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
          //Get the temp file path
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

            //Make sure we have a filepath
            if($tmpFilePath != ""){

                //save the filename
                $shortname = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                //save the url and the file
                $filePath = "uploaded/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                //Upload the file into the temp dir
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {

                    $files[] = $shortname;
                    //insert into db 
                    //use $shortname for the filename
                    //use $filePath for the relative url to the file

                }
              }
        }
    }

    //show success message
    echo "<h1>Uploaded:</h1>";    
    if(is_array($files)){
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($files as $file){
            echo "<li>$file</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
?>

<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <div>
        <label for='upload'>Add Attachments:</label>
        <input id='upload' name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>

</form>
```

**display.php**

```html
<?php


 
$files = glob("uploaded/*.*");
 
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
 
{
 
$image = $files[$i];
 
print $image ."<br />";
echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image"  height="300px" width="300px"/>'."<br /><br />";
}
 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is **edit.php**, which should handle multiple files and will also be mindful of data that was not serialized before...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"><head><!-- Created by Artisteer v4.0.0.58475 -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>library</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">
    <link href='https://sites.google.com/site/99webdemos/favicon.png' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.ie7.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.responsive.css" media="all">


    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.responsive.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
      jQuery(".form-message").fadeOut(10000);
    });
    </script>

<style>.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-0 { padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;  }
.ie7 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }
.ie6 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }

</style></head>
<body>
<div id="art-main">
    <div id="art-header-bg" class="clearfix">
            </div>
    <div id="art-hmenu-bg" class="art-bar art-nav clearfix">
    </div>
    <div class="art-sheet clearfix">
<header class="art-header clearfix">


    <div class="art-shapes">
<h1 class="art-headline" data-left="0.5%">
    <a  href="http://www.99demos.blogspot.com" target="_blank">library</a>
</h1>
<h2 class="art-slogan" data-left="87.05%"><a href="http://99demos.blogspot.in/2014/06/createreadupdate-delete-with-image.html"></a></h2>


            </div>

<nav class="art-nav clearfix">
    <div class="art-nav-inner">
    <ul class="art-hmenu"><li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li></ul> 
        </div>
    </nav>


</header>
<div class="art-layout-wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="art-content-layout">
                    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
                        <div class="art-layout-cell art-content clearfix"><article class="art-post art-article">
                                <h2 class="art-postheader">customer form</h2>

                <div class="art-postcontent art-postcontent-0 clearfix"><div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%" >
        <br>


<?php
ob_start(); 
include('include/connect.php'); 
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp where id=".$_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query($qry,$conn);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    {
        $row['image'] = @unserialize($row['image']);
        if(!is_array($row['image'])) $row['image'] = array($row['image']);
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {
            //always always always always escape...
            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
            $age = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["age"]);
            $gender= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
            $martial = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["martial"]);
            $contact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["contact"]);
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
            $location= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["location"]);
            $category= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["category"]);

            $files = array();
            if(count($_FILES['file']['name']) > 0){
                //Loop through each file
                foreach($_FILES['file']['error']  as $key => $error) {
                    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        //Get the temp file path
                        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

                        //Make sure we have a filepath
                        if($tmpFilePath != ""){

                            //save the filename
                            $shortname = date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

                            //save the url and the file
                            $filePath = "uploaded/" . $shortname;

                            //Upload the file into the temp dir
                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {

                                $files[] = $shortname;
                                //insert into db 
                                //use $shortname for the filename
                                //use $filePath for the relative url to the file

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            If(!empty($files)) {
                //get data ready for insertion
                $allFiles = mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($files));
                //remove old files
                if(!empty($row['image'])) foreach($row['image'] as $oldFile) {
                    if(file_exists('uploaded/'.$oldFile)) unlink('uploaded/'.$oldFile);
                }
            }
            else {
                if(!is_array($row['image'])) $row['image'] = array($row['image']);
                $allFiles = mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($row['image']));
            }

             $sqlAdd ="update tbl_emp set name='".$name."', age='".$age."', gender='".$gender."', martial='".$martial."', contact='".$contact."', email='".$email."', location='".$location."', category='".$category."', image='".$image_name."'  where id=".$_GET['id'];
             mysql_query($sqlAdd);
             header("Location:add.php?id=".(int) @$_GET['id']."&msg=success");
             exit;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        //always always always always escape...
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
        $age = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["age"]);
        $gender= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
        $martial = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["martial"]);
        $contact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["contact"]);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
        $location= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["location"]);
        $category= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["category"]);    


        $files = array();
        if(count($_FILES['file']['name']) > 0){
            //Loop through each file
            foreach($_FILES['file']['error']  as $key => $error) {
                if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    //Get the temp file path
                    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

                    //Make sure we have a filepath
                    if($tmpFilePath != ""){

                        //save the filename
                        $shortname = date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

                        //save the url and the file
                        $filePath = "uploaded/" . $shortname;

                        //Upload the file into the temp dir
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {

                            $files[] = $shortname;
                            //insert into db 
                            //use $shortname for the filename
                            //use $filePath for the relative url to the file

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        If(!empty($files)) {
            $allFiles = mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($files));
             $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_emp` (`name`,`age`,`gender`,`martial`,`contact`,`email`,`location`,`category`,`image`) VALUES('$name','$age','$gender','$martial','$contact','$email','$location','$category','$image_name')") ? "success":"failure";
            header("Location:index.php?msg=$result");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
    ob_end_flush();

    if(isset($_GET['msg']))
    {
    ?>
    <div style="color:red;padding-bottom:10px;" class="form-message" align="center"><b>Task completd successfully.</b></div>
    <?php   

    }
?>


<form  method="post" name="login" id="login" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table class="table" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Customer Details</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Full Name</td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Firstname Lastname" pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z-'0-9]+" required value="<?php echo @$row['name'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td width="20%">Age</td>
    <td><input name="age" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['2'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Gender</td>
 <td><input type="Radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if ($gender=='male') { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
 Male
 <input type="Radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if ($gender=='female') { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
 Female</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Martial Status</td>
    <td><input name="martial" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['4'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%">Contact Number</td>
    <td><input name="contact" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['5'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">Email Address</td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['6'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Location</td>
    <td><input name="location" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['7'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td width="10%">category</td>
    <td>
    <select name="category" id="category" value="<?php echo @$row['11'];?>">
    <option <?php if ($category== '1' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="1">1</option>
    <option <?php if ($category== '2' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="2">2</option>
    <option <?php if ($category== '3' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Image</td>
    <td><input name="file[]" type="file" multiple="" ></td>

  </tr>
   <?php
   if(!is_array($row['image'])) $row['image'] = array($row['image']);
   if(!empty($row['image']))
   {
   ?>
   <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <?php foreach($image as $row['image']): ?>
                <img src="uploads/<?=$image;?> " height="50" width="50">
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </td>
   </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" class="submit">
    <input name="submit" value="Cancel" type="button" class="submit" onClick="window.location='index.php'">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form> 
<a href="http://dme-medical.com/library/search.php">Go back to list</a>       
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</article></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<footer class="art-footer clearfix">
  <div class="art-footer-inner">
<p>Copyright © 2016. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    <p class="art-page-footer">

    </p>
  </div>
</footer>

</div>



</body></html>
```

Comment: Hello, Can you please guide me where i have to put this in my code?

Comment: i want to put my multiple code in my edit.php page and i have given upload in in the brackets in multiple.php

Comment: Sorry, I was confused for a second, and didn't realize the multiple files there.. Let me know if my latest revision helps you

Comment: $image_name is for single image upload. i want to add one more say just $image_multi. Single upload is working fine just multiple upload code i have to add in my form but i am not able to do can you help me please we will den after putting that test and see how result comes.

Comment: Yes please Many thanks for giving me time. i will wait for you reply

Comment: my multiple code is working but i want it to work like all fields in my form . now it is in separate file but i want to put in my form as one field.

Comment: I've updated my response... that is a standalone "edit.php" file

Comment: Its not working :( not even inserting values in database. i have changed fields and code a little i got something online but the thing is in this new code my it is getting preview but it is not getting add in database nor it is getting edit and update

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!----------------New Code ---------------------->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"><head><!-- Created by Artisteer v4.0.0.58475 -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>library</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">
    <link href='https://sites.google.com/site/99webdemos/favicon.png' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.ie7.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.responsive.css" media="all">


    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.responsive.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
      jQuery(".form-message").fadeOut(10000);
    });
    </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileupload");
    fileUpload.onchange = function () {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var dvPreview = document.getElementById("dvPreview");
            dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
            for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload.files.length; i++) {
                var file = fileUpload.files[i];
                if (regex.test(file.name.toLowerCase())) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                        img.height = "100";
                        img.width = "100";
                        img.src = e.target.result;
                        dvPreview.appendChild(img);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                } else {
                    alert(file.name + " is not a valid image file.");
                    dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style>.art-content .art-postcontent-0 .layout-item-0 { padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;  }
.ie7 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }
.ie6 .post .layout-cell {border:none !important; padding:0 !important; }

</style></head>
<body>
<div id="art-main">
    <div id="art-header-bg" class="clearfix">
            </div>
    <div id="art-hmenu-bg" class="art-bar art-nav clearfix">
    </div>
    <div class="art-sheet clearfix">
<header class="art-header clearfix">


    <div class="art-shapes">
<h1 class="art-headline" data-left="0.5%">
    <a  href="http://www.99demos.blogspot.com" target="_blank">library</a>
</h1>
<h2 class="art-slogan" data-left="87.05%"><a href="http://99demos.blogspot.in/2014/06/createreadupdate-delete-with-image.html"></a></h2>


            </div>

<nav class="art-nav clearfix">
    <div class="art-nav-inner">
    <ul class="art-hmenu"><li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li></ul> 
        </div>
    </nav>

                    
</header>
<div class="art-layout-wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="art-content-layout">
                    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
                        <div class="art-layout-cell art-content clearfix"><article class="art-post art-article">
                                <h2 class="art-postheader">customer form</h2>
                                                
                <div class="art-postcontent art-postcontent-0 clearfix"><div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%" >
        <br>
        
        
<?php
ob_start(); 
include('include/connect.php'); 
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

 $qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp where id=".$_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
         $age = $_POST["age"];
        $gender=$_POST['gender'];
         $martial = $_POST["martial"];
         $contact = $_POST["contact"];
         $email = $_POST["email"];
          $location= $_POST["location"];
            $drname= $_POST["drname"];
             $cname= $_POST["cname"];
              $clocation= $_POST["clocation"];
              $implants=implode(',',$_POST['implants']);
               $problem= $_POST["problem"];
              $tgiven= $_POST["tgiven"];
               $tdate= $_POST["tdate"];
        IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
        {
     $file='uploads/'.$row['image'];
     @unlink($file);
                 $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
              $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
     $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
     $image_name=time().".".$ext;
              $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
  }
  else
  {
    $image_name=$row['image'];
  }
  
     $sqlAdd ="update tbl_emp set name='".$name."', age='".$age."', gender='".$gender."', martial='".$martial."', contact='".$contact."', email='".$email."', location='".$location."', drname='".$drname."', cname='".$cname."', clocation='".$clocation."', implants='".$implants."', problem='".$problem."', tgiven='".$tgiven."', tdate='".$tdate."', image='".$image_name."'  where id=".$_GET['id'];
     mysql_query($sqlAdd);
         header("Location:add.php?id=".@$_GET['id']."&msg=success");
   exit;
    }  
}
else
{
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
       $age = $_POST["age"];
     $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        $martial = $_POST["martial"];
        $contact = $_POST["contact"];
         $email = $_POST["email"];
          $location= $_POST["location"];
            $drname= $_POST["drname"];
             $cname= $_POST["cname"];
              $clocation= $_POST["clocation"];
                $implants= $_POST["implants"];
                
                $problem= $_POST["problem"];
              $tgiven= $_POST["tgiven"];
               $tdate= $_POST["tdate"];
        IF($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
   $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
   $image_name=time().".".$ext;

            $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/".$image_name);
        }
        $sqlAdd = mysql_query("insert into tbl_emp(name,age,gender,martial,contact,email,location,drname,cname,clocation,implants,problem,tgiven,tdate,image) VALUES('$name','$age','$gender','$martial','$contact','$email','$location','$drname','$cname','$clocation','$implants','$problem','$tgiven','$tdate','$image_name')");
        header("Location:index.php?msg=success");
  exit;
    }
}
    ob_end_flush();
 
 if(isset($_GET['msg']))
 {
 ?>
    <div style="color:red;padding-bottom:10px;" class="form-message" align="center"><b>Task completd successfully.</b></div>
    <?php 
 }
?>


<form  method="post" name="login" id="login" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <table class="table" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Customer Details</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Full Name</td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Firstname Lastname" pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z-'0-9]+" required value="<?php echo @$row['name'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td width="20%">Age</td>
    <td><input name="age" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['2'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Gender</td>
 <td><input type="Radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if ($gender=='male') { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
 Male
 <input type="Radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if ($gender=='female') { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
 Female</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Martial Status</td>
    <td><input name="martial" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['4'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%">Contact Number</td>
    <td><input name="contact" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['5'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">Email Address</td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['6'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Location</td>
    <td><input name="location" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['7'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">Treatment Details</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">Doctor Name</td>
    <td><input name="drname" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['8'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">Clinic Name</td>
    <td><input name="cname" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['9'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">Clinic Location & Branch</td>
    <td><input name="clocation" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['10'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="10%">Implants</td>
    <td>
    
    <select name="implants"  id="implants" value="<?php echo @$row['11'];?>">
    <option <?php if ($implants== '1' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="1">1</option>
    <option <?php if ($implants== '2' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="2">2</option>
    <option <?php if ($implants== '3' ) echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Problem</td>
    <td><input name="problem" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['12'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Treatment Given</td>
    <td><input name="tgiven" type="text" value="<?php echo @$row['13'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Treatment Date</td>
    <td><input name="tdate" type="date" value="<?php echo @$row['14'];?>" ></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>multifile
  <td>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
<hr />
<b>Live Preview</b>
<br />
<br />
<div id="dvPreview">
</div>
</td>
  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">X-Ray Image</td>
    <td><input name="file" type="file" multiple="" ></td>
    
  </tr>
   <?php
   if(isset($row['image'])) 
   {
   ?>
   <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image'];?> " height="50" width="50"></td>
   </tr>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" class="submit">
    <input name="submit" value="Cancel" type="button" class="submit" onClick="window.location='index.php'">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
        
        
        
        
        
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</article></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<footer class="art-footer clearfix">
  <div class="art-footer-inner">
<p>Copyright © 2016. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    <p class="art-page-footer">
      
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>

</div>


</body></html>

<!-------------End of new code------------------->
```

```html
<?php


 
$files = glob("uploaded/*.*");
 
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
 
{
 
$image = $files[$i];
 
print $image ."<br />";
echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image"  height="300px" width="300px"/>'."<br /><br />";
}
 
?>
```